# How to replace \r\n with a line break

Tags: php

I have a comment system in PHP, and when a user types a line break in the textarea it shows up as rn (Note: I'm sanitizing this input and using htmlentities(), and I have custom mark-up).

Here's my current code (including attempt at line break replacement):

```
$comment_content =stripslashes(str_replace('\r\n', '@//', mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['comment_content'])));
$comment_content = htmlentities($comment_content);
$comment_content = mysql_real_escape_string(str_replace("====", "<span class=".$bold.">", $comment_content));
$comment_content = mysql_real_escape_string(str_replace("===", "</span>", $comment_content));
$comment_content = mysql_real_escape_string(str_replace("~~~", "<span class=".$italic.">", $comment_content));
$comment_content = mysql_real_escape_string(str_replace("~~", "</span>", $comment_content));
$comment_content = mysql_real_escape_string(str_replace("++++", "<span class=".$big.">", $comment_content));
$comment_content = mysql_real_escape_string(str_replace("+++", "</span>", $comment_content));
$comment_content = mysql_real_escape_string(str_replace("___", "<span class=".$underline.">", $comment_content));
$comment_content = mysql_real_escape_string(str_replace("__", "</span>", $comment_content));
$comment_content = mysql_real_escape_string(str_replace("@//", "<br>", $comment_content));
$comment_content = comment_sanitize($comment_content);
```

And this is how I sanitize:

```
function sanitize($sql, $formUse = true) {
    $sql = preg_replace("/(from|script|src|select|insert|delete|where|drop table|show tables|`|,|'|\*|\\\\)/i","",$sql);
    $sql = trim($sql);
    if(!$formUse || !get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $sql = addslashes($sql);
    }
    return $sql;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What are you doing to sanitize the input? Try... doing something else.

Comment: PHP's native function `nl2br()` is the quick and dirty way.

Comment: Wooble, I'm using custom sanitization code. ceejayoz, Thanks. j08691, Ok, will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't use `htmlentities` on the way in, you use it on the output. You should be escaping to input into your database and then to display newlines on the output consider:

```
nl2br(htmlentities($comment));
```

Comment: Well, see, the thing is, I have my own mark-up for this comment system, and it changed something like ~~~Underline Text~~ to <span class="underline">Underline Text</span>. I'll post  my code in a bit so you can see what I mean.

Comment: @Zbee if you perform the nl2br/htmlentities first you can still do all of your replacements and they wont be escaped prior to output.

Comment: So, if I have <span>Span-ness</span> in my database as a comment and echo that comment as htmlentitites($comment) it would simply echo "Span-ness" in a <span> tag?

Comment: @Zbee I would recommend doing the replacement after the `SELECT` not before the `INSERT`.. That way you can tweak your styling without a major headache at a later date